# Installer not listing disks

Tags: dual-boot, disk-management

I'm trying to triple boot my MacBook 15,1 using [these instructions](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/triple-booting-a-mac/). I have of course mac (latest) and windows booting but I'm failing to install latest Elementary OS.

I burned the iso to a usb stick. That boots fine and I can launch the installer. But the installer does not list the mac's SSD drive so I can't finish partitioning the empty space and install linux.

The only disk the installer shows is the USB stick.

Any ideas how to solve this?